Is there any way to get chromium to use overlay scrollbars via CSS?
The 'scrollbar styling' chrome dev article talkts about 'classic' and 'overlay' scrollbars
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/css-ui/scrollbar-styling#classic_and_overlay_scrollbars
I'm working on a UI that runs inside an embedded chromium (vuplex webview) inside the application.
I am supposed to implement a design that uses overlay scrollbars.
I heard there is a flag to make chrome use overlay scrollbars (that apparently seems to come and go with versions) - but the problem is, I don'T know if there even is a way to make that embedded chromium use these flags.
I also found a few questions in that direction, but no answers.
I tried playing around with scrollbar-gutter, &::-webkit-scrollbar+width, but I couldn't come up with a solution: when the vertical scrollbar is visible, the scrollbar-gutter will always 'steal' away space on the right side of the div that should be scrollable.
Is it really impossible to make chromium use an overlay scrollbar?
Is there any way to hack it?

Plenty of JS plugins available to create such overlay scrollbars, maybe you want to look into one of those? Like f.e. https://kingsora.github.io/OverlayScrollbars/

Somehow I was just hoping there existed a solution that just somehow uses native scrollbars and doesn't require to hide them, put custom html elements and hook them up with js .... already had to go that way with other elements like sliders to make them work as desired, but probably in the end I will have to go this route.
Thanks - I'll definitely check the library out.
